# Sending response before processing in Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, printwriter

I have a Java Servlet application running on JBoss 4 and this application receives POST request from another service. I want to acknowledge back to this service before processing. Is it fine to do the following?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {

 readReceivedPOSTData();

 //send response
 PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
 out.print("ack");
 out.close();

 //Process
 processData(); //takes long time

}
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The basis is ok.

Just some tips:

- Use an identifier in the request so you can check in the future the status of that request.
- Start another thread to process the data or use a jms queue
- remember that you can't write additional data to the response in the `processData()` method

Comment: Thanks David. I just want to acknowledge the service that i have received the data. I don't want to add additional data to the response.